# SharePoint hosted App without configuring DNS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Hi I have a SharePoint Dev envrionment one single machine but I have no permissions to configure DNS, so DNS has not been configured and there is no app domain for apps. When I deploy my app from Visual Studio, it generates 404 error. Is it possible to make it work without configuring DNS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a subscription of SharePoint Online and deploy and debug your applications directly in the cloud. See here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/apps/fp179924(v=office.15)

Also, you can directly deploy your SharePoint Hosted App to the Office 365 Developer Site from Visual Studio 2012.